# enter link with query string without reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to achieve something like this

[image: Expect result 1]

with clean history

[image: Expect result 2]

I want to do in `<a>` tag look like `<a href="...?theme=dark...">`

or I need to do in `javascript` with something like `window.location.href... = mainURL + '?theme=dark'`

**How to achieve like the images above?**

> addition question: How to also possibly achieve in IE?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3503206#3503206) answer your question?

Comment: Thank guys, I'm new to `history.pushstate...` I also try but is it good practice to do like `window.history.replaceState('','','?theme='+ obj.theme)` right now it works for me. by the way `obj.theme = 'dark'`